# How to pass a mutable self reference on to a trait method?

Tags: rust

While working through the [OOP-Chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch17-03-oo-design-patterns.html) of the Rust book (2nd Edition) I took on the optional task to implement the method `add_text` for the following struct

```
pub struct Post {
    state: Option<Box<State>>,
    content: String,
}
```

There are three structs that implement the `State` trait, but only the `Draft` struct should actually do something. I implemented this as follows

```
trait State {
    // snip
    fn add_text(&self, post: &mut Post, text: &str) { }
}


struct Draft { }

impl State for Draft {
    // snip
    fn add_text(&self, post: &mut Post, text: &str) {
        post.content.push_str(text);
    }
}
```

My problem is that in order to get the `State` from my post struct to call the `add_text` method I immutably borrow `self` (in `Post`) and can not pass on a mutable reference to the `add_text` method of the `State` trait:

```
impl Post {
    // snip

    pub fn add_text(&mut self, text: &str){
        let state = self.state.as_ref().unwrap();  // This immutably borrows self
        state.add_text(self, text);  // so that this mutable borrow is no longer possible
    }
}
```

How do I deal with this dilemma? I definitely need a mutable reference to the `Post`, otherwise I can't change its text. On the other hand, I need to get the `State` first since otherwise I can not even call the method.

One way to work around this would be be to change `add_text` to `get_text_to_add` which would not require mutability of the `Post`, but I would like to make sure that I am not overseeing any options to solve this.

Comment: This to me looks like a code smell. First, the `State::add_text` method impl on `Draft` has nothing to do with the `Draft` struct _whatsoever_ - you might as well remove the `&self` parameter and be done with it. Second, as an external consumer of this hypothetical library I'd expect the `add_text` method to be on the `Post` struct itself. You would be much better off moving `add_text` to `Post`, and looking up information or mutating the `state` field as and when needed. If you only want to `add_text` if the post is a draft, you can check if `self.state` is a `Draft` inside `Post::add_text`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With structs Rust is smart enough to be able to do disjoint borrows so you don't need to pass a mutable reference to the entire `Post` struct, just the part of it you need to modify (in this case content).

```
trait State {
    // snip

    // Modify the method on the add_text trait so that it
    // takes a mutable reference to String
    fn add_text(&self, content: &mut String, text: &str) { }
}

struct Draft { }

impl State for Draft {
    // snip

    // Update the implementation of State for Draft so that it
    // matches the new signature
    fn add_text(&self, content: &mut String, text: &str) {
        content.push_str(text);
    }
}

impl Post {
    // snip

    pub fn add_text(&mut self, text: &str){
        let state = self.state.as_ref().unwrap();  

        // Now when you call add_text you don't require a mutable 
        // reference to self, just to self.content and so the 
        // borrow checker is happy
        state.add_text(&mut self.content, text);  
    }
}
```

This should work but it feels a bit forced, (as EvilTak points out the reference to self in `Draft::add_text` is redundant). I guess that's part of the point of the exercise though; while it is possible to implement certain patterns from OOP in Rust there are better ways to model the problem.

Comment: Thank you, this approach did not occur to me. I agree with both you and @EvilTak that this most likely is a bad way to do this (hence, the last paragraph of my question). On the other hand, this was a nice opportunity to learn more about borrowing, so thanks for helping me with that. I will accept an answer on Monday.